# Can flexbox sidebars share a new row?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

Can I get flexbox sidebars to share a new row, after a media query?

Before (on wide screens)

```
+---+-------+---+
|   |       |   |
| L |  Main | R |
|   |       |   |
+---+-------+---+
```

After (on narrow screens)

```
+-------+
|       |
|  Main |
|       |
+-------+
|   |   |
| L | R |
|   |   |
+-------+
```

HTML (not changeable after media query)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="sideLeft">L</div>
  <div class="MainContent">Main</div>
  <div class="sideRight">R</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does your CSS look like?

Comment: I didn't get as far as the CSS, because I didn't know whether the flexbox model could do it. I know it can stack them all one above the other in any order. But here is my first attempt: https://jsfiddle.net/0tb5yyto/
I also tried adding flex-wrap:nowrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change `order: -1` on `main` div with media queries. You also need to set `flex-wrap: wrap` on `container` element. Also `calc(% - 10px)` is for `margin` of 5px on both sides but if you don't want margins you can just use % as you can se [`here`](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1312/)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 5px
}
.container > div {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  flex: 1;
}
div.main {
  flex: 3;
}
@media(max-width: 480px) {
  div.main {
    order: -1;
    flex: 0 0 calc(100% - 10px);
  }
  .container > div:not(.main) {
    flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 10px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sideLeft">L</div>
  <div class="main">Main</div>
  <div class="sideRight">R</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, you're a genius. Now I just have to understand what you did, and why it works! It's a lot more complicated than I anticipated.

Comment: You're welcome, its not that hard, you can read more about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes